# Windows 10 IoT: exception code e0434352 causes?

Tags: debugging, runtime-error, windows-10-iot-core, appx

I'm attempting to repackage a Desktop app (the code to which I do not have) for Windows 10 IoT using PACE Converter (basically a wrapped-up Desktop Bridge).

I've gotten to the point where I can install it on my device (actually a Minnowboard VM) using the Device Portal website, but I cannot run it. 
The app instantly crashes, and provides the following log output:

```
Version=1
EventType=MoAppCrash
EventTime=131650324486808277
ReportType=2
Consent=1
UploadTime=131650324491343532
ReportIdentifier=0729d269-2339-11e8-844f-000c29c53adc
IntegratorReportIdentifier=0ac9bcb5-b460-4475-bdb5-86a8f0c18281
NsAppName=praid:ThermoVisionJoeC
Response.BucketId=d94813fac3d80d13b0156e9965e35ba5
Response.BucketTable=5
Response.LegacyBucketId=1158954084236221349
Response.type=4
Response.CabId=2077997148494651244
Sig[0].Name=Package Full Name
Sig[0].Value=ThermoVisionversion1.8_1.8.0.0_x86__69vzfematcnkr
Sig[1].Name=Application Name
Sig[1].Value=praid:ThermoVisionJoeC
Sig[2].Name=Application Version
Sig[2].Value=1.8.0.0
Sig[3].Name=Application Timestamp
Sig[3].Value=5a2a86fb
Sig[4].Name=Fault Module Name
Sig[4].Value=kernelbase.dll
Sig[5].Name=Fault Module Version
Sig[5].Value=10.0.10586.0
Sig[6].Name=Fault Module Timestamp
Sig[6].Value=5632d1bc
Sig[7].Name=Exception Code
Sig[7].Value=e0434352
Sig[8].Name=Exception Offset
Sig[8].Value=000d2ed2
DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version
DynamicSig[1].Value=10.0.10586.2.0.0.256.123
DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID
DynamicSig[2].Value=1033
DynamicSig[22].Name=Additional Information 1
DynamicSig[22].Value=7d75
DynamicSig[23].Name=Additional Information 2
DynamicSig[23].Value=7d75e07ca427d63ce5d6b2980c892ce4
DynamicSig[24].Name=Additional Information 3
DynamicSig[24].Value=2a76
DynamicSig[25].Name=Additional Information 4
DynamicSig[25].Value=2a7669b2a9a5dd27db4411a185741431
UI[2]=c:\data\Programs\WindowsApps\ThermoVisionversion1.8_1.8.0.0_x86__69vzfematcnkr\TVision_V1.8.0.0\ThermoVision_JoeC.exe
LoadedModule[0]=c:\data\Programs\WindowsApps\ThermoVisionversion1.8_1.8.0.0_x86__69vzfematcnkr\TVision_V1.8.0.0\ThermoVision_JoeC.exe
LoadedModule[1]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\MSCOREE.DLL
LoadedModule[3]=C:\windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\windows\system32\kernelbase.dll
LoadedModule[5]=C:\windows\system32\combase.dll
LoadedModule[6]=C:\windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
LoadedModule[7]=C:\windows\system32\kernel32legacy.dll
LoadedModule[8]=C:\windows\system32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
LoadedModule[9]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\kernel.appcore.dll
LoadedModule[10]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\shcore.dll
LoadedModule[11]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\wintypes.dll
LoadedModule[12]=C:\windows\system32\CoreClr\v1.0\CoreClr.dll
LoadedModule[13]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll
LoadedModule[14]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll
LoadedModule[15]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\OLEAUT32.dll
LoadedModule[16]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\advapi32legacy.dll
LoadedModule[17]=C:\windows\system32\sechost.dll
LoadedModule[18]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPT32.dll
LoadedModule[19]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll
LoadedModule[20]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\MSASN1.dll
LoadedModule[21]=C:\windows\system32\CoreClr\v1.0\mscorlib.ni.dll
LoadedModule[22]=C:\windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
LoadedModule[23]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll
LoadedModule[24]=C:\windows\system32\CoreClr\v1.0\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.ni.dll
LoadedModule[25]=C:\windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.Foundation.winmd
LoadedModule[26]=C:\windows\system32\CoreClr\v1.0\System.Runtime.ni.dll
LoadedModule[27]=C:\windows\system32\CoreClr\v1.0\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.ni.dll
LoadedModule[28]=C:\windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.ApplicationModel.winmd
LoadedModule[29]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\procthreadexthost.dll
LoadedModule[30]=c:\Windows\System32\MrmCoreR.dll
LoadedModule[31]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\profapi.dll
LoadedModule[32]=c:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.dll
LoadedModule[33]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\dcomp.dll
LoadedModule[34]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\minuser.dll
LoadedModule[35]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\GDI32.dll
LoadedModule[36]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\CoreUIComponents.dll
LoadedModule[37]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\CoreMessaging.dll
LoadedModule[38]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\Bcp47Langs.dll
LoadedModule[39]=c:\Windows\System32\twinapi.appcore.dll
LoadedModule[40]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\faultrep.dll
LoadedModule[41]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll
LoadedModule[42]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\dbgcore.DLL
State[0].Key=Transport.DoneStage1
State[0].Value=1
File[0].CabName=WERInternalMetadata.xml
File[0].Path=WER815.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
File[0].Flags=851970
File[0].Type=5
File[0].Original.Path=C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\Temp\WER815.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
File[1].CabName=triagedump.dmp
File[1].Path=triagedump.dmp
File[1].Flags=808255490
File[1].Type=6
File[2].CabName=WERGenerationLog.txt
File[2].Flags=851970
File[2].Type=5
File[2].Buffer=FFFE53006E0061007000730068006F0074002000640075006D007000650072002000640065006100630074006900760061007400650064002E000D000A002D002000200053006E0061007000730068006F007400200061007600610069006C00610062006C0065003A00200030002E000D000A002D002000200053006E0061007000730068006F00740073002000640069007300610062006C00650064003A002000300030002E000D000A002D002000200020002000200053006E0061007000730068006F00740020007300740061007400750073003A002000430030003000300030003000310037002E000D000A002D002000200020002000200020002000440075006D0070006500720020007300740061007400750073003A002000300030003000300030003000300031002E000D000A002D00200020002000500072006F0063006500730073002000570045005200200066006C006100670073003A002000300030003000300030003000300030002E000D000A002D00200057006100740073006F006E00200072006500710075006500730074002000640075006D0070003A002000300030003100300030003100410034002E000D000A000D000A0053006E0061007000730068006F0074002000640075006D007000650072002000640065006100630074006900760061007400650064002E000D000A002D002000200053006E0061007000730068006F007400200061007600610069006C00610062006C0065003A00200030002E000D000A002D002000200053006E0061007000730068006F00740073002000640069007300610062006C00650064003A002000300030002E000D000A002D002000200020002000200053006E0061007000730068006F00740020007300740061007400750073003A002000430030003000300030003000310037002E000D000A002D002000200020002000200020002000440075006D0070006500720020007300740061007400750073003A002000300030003000300030003000300031002E000D000A002D00200020002000500072006F0063006500730073002000570045005200200066006C006100670073003A002000300030003000300030003000300030002E000D000A002D00200057006100740073006F006E00200072006500710075006500730074002000640075006D0070003A002000300030003100300030003100410034002E000D000A000D000A00
File[3].CabName=memory.csv
File[3].Path=WERD53.tmp.csv
File[3].Flags=851971
File[3].Type=5
File[3].Original.Path=C:\Data\SystemData\Temp\WERD53.tmp.csv
File[4].CabName=Report.cab
File[4].Path=Report.cab
File[4].Flags=196608
File[4].Type=11
File[4].Original.Path=Report.cab
FriendlyEventName=Stopped working
ConsentKey=MoAppCrash
AppName=ThermoVisionversion1.8_69vzfematcnkr!ThermoVisionJoeC
AppPath=c:\data\Programs\WindowsApps\ThermoVisionversion1.8_1.8.0.0_x86__69vzfematcnkr\TVision_V1.8.0.0\ThermoVision_JoeC.exe
NsPartner=windows
NsGroup=windows8
ApplicationIdentity=4DCF491271EABACC61BC8E205D766FEB
```

I'm not a programmer, but I've gotten this far by educated poking at stuff and I'd like to know what to prod next (or refer to the author of the code).

Any tips?

Cheers,
R

Comment: Can the repackaged app run on Windows 10 desktop?

Comment: Yeah, it does. It's not signed correctly, but if you bypass that with PowerShell it works fine.

Comment: How did you install the app from Device Portal, steps, and files list?

Comment: Apps->Install app; selected my package.appx with no dependencies or other files.
Clicked "Go", then it said uploading and successfully installed.
After that it appears in the drop down of installed apps, but when I click start I get a popup which says "App failed to start".
I also tried it on my real hardware with a more updated version of the OS (16299.309 vs 15063), but the behaviour is exactly the same.

Comment: Instead of PowerShell method, another way is to [sign your app with a certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter#optional-parameters) and [install the certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/import-certificate?view=win10-ps) before running the app. You can have a try to see if it helps.